# first order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Is there any solution formula for a differential equation like this
$$
y'(x)=f(x)y(x)+g(x)y(ax)\qquad \text{where}\qquad a\gt1.
$$
I have a differential equation a little more complicated than this. The basic difficulty for me is that, I don't know how to deal with $y(ax)$.

Thank you.

Comment: If you write $t=\log x$, then this turns into a delay differential equation. These are known to be hard.

Comment: I put the maths into LaTeX.

Comment: why don't you put the example that you have ??

Answer (score 4):

Even for the simplest equation of this sort, $y'=y(ax)$, there is no simple formula.
Substitute a power series at $0$, and you obtain a series which is divergent when $|a|>1$.
This shows that there is no solution analytic at $0$.
(If $|a|\leq 1$ this series is convergent everywhere, but still no formula is known
simpler than the series itself.)
On the other hand, you can reduce to a differential-difference equation, as Anthony Quas recommends, and if $f$ and $g$
are constants, this differential-difference (DD) equation can be solved with
Fourier or Laplace transform, depending on your assumptions
about $y$. Of course the DD equation always has infinitely many simple 
discontinuous solutions,
depending on an arbitrary function, but probably this is not what you are looking for.